# Connect Selenium to an existing chrome browser problem - Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to connect Selenium to an existing chrome driver I execute this command in cmd `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9878` but when I try to connect to this browser it stuck at `webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)` even though it was working.

My code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9878")
chrome_driver = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=chrome_options) # stuck here
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: Please try `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9878 --user-data-dir="C:\selenium\ChromeProfile` and let me know

Comment: You will need to get the sessionID from the first chromedriver, then use that in the 2nd.  (Note:  I think when you initiate the 2nd chromedriver it will always start a new browser... so you'll have a sort of orphaned browser there.)

Comment: @pcalkins for this process getting session id is not required because you will be launching chrome by desired port.